# mysql query updating with subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

Hello i need to perform the following query

**Query**

```
update Taxonomy
set sourceId = (
select id from TaxonomyMapping a where a.oldId = 
    (
        select cm.en_ID
        from TaxonomyMapping ta 
        join CategoryMapping cm on ta.oldId = cm.language_ID where ta.oldId = oldId limit 1
    ) 
) where id > -1;
```

**The tables are as following:**

Taxonomy(id, oldId, sourceId, name, language)

TaxonomyMapping(id, oldId, sourceId, name, language) Exact copy of Taxonomy

CategoryMapping(en_ID, language_ID)

**What im trying to accomplish**
The original taxonomy table has got categories in a certain language there are translations of it, but the need they are known in Category mapping, now i need to add the english translation to the sourceId, Can somebody help me with this? at the moment it fills one id for all im suspecting that the oldId(ta.oldId = oldId) i use is not the oldId of the table to update. Is it possible to do a query like this or should i search for another solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have placed the same question in dba.stackexchange.com the answer given to me was the right one this was the query i was looking for:

```
UPDATE Taxonomy t
 JOIN CategoryMapping cm ON cm.language_ID = t.oldID
 JOIN (SELECT * FROM Taxonomy) x ON x.oldID = cm.en_ID
 SET t.sourceId = x.id
WHERE t.id > -1;
```

source: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50981/mysql-update-query-with-subquery